# Does numpy have a module named math?

Tags: python, python-module

how is this possible?

I tried using math.sqrt without ever importing math

from numpy import *
math.sqrt(25)
5.0

and got a valid result

Comment: Just use `import numpy as np` then look at the result of `np.math`. This should answer your question. You will find that it is the same module as python's `math`. i.e  `np.math.sqrt == math.sqrt`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`from numpy import *` makes namespace [numpy.math](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html) available as `math` in the current scope.

Comment: is math.isnan() enclosed ??

Comment: that link is not to `numpy.math`, it's numpy's "math routines". `numpy.math` is the same as built-in `math` module: `import math, numpy; math is numpy.math`

Comment: so math.isnan() should be there

Comment: @pippo1980 Should be where? That link is wrong.

Comment: there means I can use it whit: from numpy import *

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a valid function, according to [their reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.math.html#miscellaneous).

Comment: it says numpy.sqrt  got answer below to clarify it